# Combine multiple csv files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hta

Any ideas on how to combine multiple csv files into one using JavaScript in a HTA?

Edit:
No worries I combined several concepts and wrote some code to do it.

Comment: Can you please show us your attempt at doing so?

Comment: You can just concatenate them.

Comment: @JBDouble05 I don’t know how, that’s why I’m asking? There didn’t seem to be any stuff from search results as people don’t really use hta’s anymore (htas have full file system access)

Comment: @Physicsman if you attempt to and discover a problem, then you can ask a question. StafkOverflow is about fixing problems, not sting code.

Comment: @JBDouble05 it’s a simple solution that requires a few lines of code. I can do it in other languages, just not this one. I posted my problem as was asking for a simple solution, not sting code.

Comment: Sorry, I mean writing code. You need to have at least attempted to do so yourself before asking a question here.

Comment: @JBDouble05 oh okay sorry I’ll write some later

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution out of the box : 
you can use the CMD commands like a silent command in JS and simply write :

C:\yourdirWhereCsvfilesExist\copy *.csv combinedfile.csv

then you will have a single file called combinedfile.csv with all the data and then work with it on javascript

I hope that's will be helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks, that was the method I was previously using but it wasn’t as fast as I would have liked so I wrote some code to do it in JavaScript to do it quicker.